# Can a contract hold the leftover gas for later transactions

Tags: solidity, gas

Is it possible to leave some gas in a contract for future action and / or top up if the contract is stuck. if yes could you please direct me to documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can put some ether on contract’s balance, but contracts do not have a possibility to pay for transactions. There always should be a normal user account (i.e. not smart contract) paying for a transaction.

Comment: Thank you for your kind respond, will delete the message shortly,

Comment: I'm just wondering If person A wants to interact with person B through a contract and pays for the transaction / Gas. what is the right approach ?

Comment: I'm trying to keep it automated & decentralised